# Is there an easy way to calculate this infinite summation

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, improper-integrals

Is there an easy way to calculate this summation of integral:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{r=0}^1 \frac {(r-\frac{1}{2})\cos(c\cdot\ln(r+n))} {(r+n)^{1-b}} dr $$

The most obvious approach is to calculate the integral which I did by using https://www.integral-calculator.com/ and got a terribly long answer for a single term.

$-\dfrac{\left(n+1\right)^b\left(\left(4b+2\right)cn-c^3+\left(-b^2+2b+1\right)c\right)\sin\left(c\ln\left(n+1\right)\right)+\left(n+1\right)^b\left(\left(-2c^2+2b^2+2b\right)n+\left(-b-2\right)c^2-b^3+b\right)\cos\left(c\ln\left(n+1\right)\right)+n^b\cdot\left(\left(-4b-2\right)cn-c^3+\left(-b^2-2b-1\right)c\right)\sin\left(c\ln\left(n\right)\right)+n^b\cdot\left(\left(2c^2-2b^2-2b\right)n-bc^2-b^3-2b^2-b\right)\cos\left(c\ln\left(n\right)\right)}{2\left(c^4+\left(2b^2+2b+1\right)c^2+b^4+2b^3+b^2\right)}$

But this seems an absurd way to even try. There has to be a better and simpler way to solve this. So can someone please help with calculating this series? I don't have much clue how to approach it?

We are assuming that the constants $b, c$ are such that the series is convergent if that helps.

If simplifying this in not possible how do we proceed further. How do we find the summation of this infinite series? Is it possible to convert it into an integral that can be explicitly calculated? If so can someone please demonstrate it how ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Mathematica one gets

```
  ((r - 1/2) Cos[c Log[r + n]])/(r + n)^(1 - b) //  TrigToExp // FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{1}{4} (2 r-1) \left(1+(n+r)^{2 i c}\right) (n+r)^{b-i c-1}$$

```
int= Integrate [1/4 (n+r)^(-1+b-I c) (-1+2 r) (1+(n+r)^(2 I c)),r]//Together//FullSimplify
```

$$\text{int}=\frac{1}{4}  \ (n+r)^{b-i c} \left(-\frac{(n+r)^{2 i c} (-2 b r+b+i c (1-2 r)+2 n+1)}{(b+i c) (b+i c+1)}-\frac{-2 b r+b+i c (2 r-1)+2 n+1}{(b-i c) (b-i c+1)}\right)$$

Taking the limits r=1  - r =0

$$\frac{1}{4}   \left(\frac{(b+i c+2 n+1) n^{b+i c}}{(b+i c) (b+i c+1)}+\frac{(b-i c+2 n+1) n^{b-i c}}{(b-i c) (b-i c+1)}+\frac{(n+1)^{b+i c} (b+i c-2 n-1)}{(b+i c) (b+i c+1)}+\frac{(n+1)^{b-i c} (b-i c-2 n-1)}{(b-i c) (b-i c+1)}\right)$$

Ignoring the constants

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (n+1)^{b-i c} =\text{Zeta}[-b + I c]$$

and

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } n (n+1)^{b-i c} = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } ((n+1)-1) (n+1)^{b-i c}$$

etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I have a few doubts. it seems we are transforming one infinite summation into another. Moreover we managed to transform a real summation into one involving complex numbers. But, I still don't know how to calculate the value of the original series. Naively I think it has to be a real value since the input is a summation of real series. So how does this solve the purpose? Can you please explain.

Comment: Why can't we find the exact real summation value without resorting to this transformation. Is it possible to transform the infinite summation into an integral and solving that resulting in an equation on real numbers only? I think it should be possible. But don't know how.

Comment: any comments please?

Comment: $$\cos(c \log(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left( e^{i c \log(x}) + e^{-i c \log(x)}\right)  = \frac{1}{2}  \ (x^{i c} + 1/x^{{i c t }})$$ for $x>0, c_0$  is a definition, there is no other one. Taking the integral over $x\in (0,1)$ yields a real result, because the complex expression is the real part of that exponential. It remains to evaluate the eight different $\zeta$ sums with the constant coefficients in that representation and compare it with special numeric integrals and sums for exclusion of errors in the algebraic transformations.

Comment: thank you. but I am somewhat of a novice and this whole part: "It remains to evaluate ...algebraic transformations" is extremely unclear. I hope not bothering you much but if possible can you explain at that level. As I interpret you are saying that the complex expression is unavoidable. ok. i get that. but we have managed to change one series into another. but i don't know how to evaluate the second series under the "taking the limits part" either.

Comment: For the limits part: Mathematica often does not or only after long time find a definite integral despite the fact that the indefinite integrals are easy. Therefore any integrand expression should expanded in sums of products of constants multplied by functions to be integrated.
$$\int_0^1(  a f(x) + b g(x) + \dots ) = \left(  a \int f(x) dx + b g(x)dx  + \dots  \right)_0^1$$

Comment: For the limits part: Mathematica often does not or only after long time find a definite integral despite the fact that the indefinite integrals are easy. Therefore any integrand expression should expanded in sums of products of constants multplied by functions to be integrated.
$$\int_0^1(  a f(x) + b g(x) + \dots ) = \left(  a \int f(x) dx + b \int g(x)dx  + \dots  \right)_0^1$$ where the limits at the outer bracket means difference of the eavulation of the indefinite integrals obtained.

Comment: I understand what you said but i am not sure its relation to my Q so here is my doubt: $\frac{1}{4}   \left(\frac{(b+i c+2 n+1) n^{b+i c}}{(b+i c) (b+i c+1)}+\frac{(b-i c+2 n+1) n^{b-i c}}{(b-i c) (b-i c+1)}+\frac{(n+1)^{b+i c} (b+i c-2 n-1)}{(b+i c) (b+i c+1)}+\frac{(n+1)^{b-i c} (b-i c-2 n-1)}{(b-i c) (b-i c+1)}\right)$ We reached here. Now, this is one term of the infinite summation series. So, we transformed first series into this series. But I am lost how we solve this second summation series? I am still lost here.

Comment: Each fraction consists of a constant  denominator   and a numerator of the form $$  a n^{b+ic} + 2 n^{b+ i c + 1}$$  or $$a (n+1)^{b+ic} + 2 (n+1)^{b+ i c + 1}$$ by adding a constant to the $2n$ factor. Each summand can be summed over $n$ yielding a zeta function multiplied with the  constants isolated. Of course, the zeta functions are abbreviations of the sums only, so there is no real algebraic insight.